# need to populate hashmap on startup from database hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

This is where my hashmap is defined and i need to populate the map on everytime the app restarts  is it done by hbm.xml?
 public class MMTUtil
    {

```
private static Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap = null;

static
{
    domainDocumentationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    domainComboDocumentationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public static Map<String, String> getDomainDocumentationMap(){
    return domainDocumentationMap;
}

public static void setDomainDocumentationMap(String objectName, String documentationLink) {
    MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap.put(objectName, documentationLink);
}
```

this is my hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.navteq.umr.dto">
<class name="UMRDocumentationDTO" table="UMR_DOCUMENTATION">
    <composite-id name="id" class="UMRDocumentationDTO$Id">
        <key-property name="objectType" type="string" column="OBJECT_TYPE"
            length="50">
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="objectName" type="string" column="OBJECT_NAME"
            length="500">
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <!-- <property name="objectType" type="string" column="OBJECT_TYPE" length="50"> 
        </property> <property name="objectName" type="string" column="OBJECT_NAME" 
        length="500"> </property> -->
    <property name="documentationLink" type="string" column="DOCUMENTATION_LINK"
        length="1000">
    </property>
</class>
```

what shall I do , or what approach shall i take?